# Catch react native warnings

Tags: react-native, sentry, react-native-sentry

I integrated @sentry/react-native SDK Version 1.30. And catching errors work well. But the warnings not sent to Sentry.

Is it possible to catch react native warnings (YellowBox warnings) for logging with sentry?